# Error Cors en Laravel 5.5, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: laravel, angular

he intentado agregando un middleware llamado Cors.php con el siguiente codigo

```
    return  $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type");
```

en el archivo kernel.php agrege la siguiente linea en le arreglo de middlewares

\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,

el llamado a la  api lo hago desde angular, el codigo anterior solo me funciona con el metodo Get pero no con Put ni Post

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que elimines ese codigo e instales un paquete que te resuelve todo eso muy facil

[Laravel Cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

Te enlisto los pasos

- composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
- En app/Http/Kernel.php agrega en la parte de $middleware
- \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,

Con eso quedaria configurado